# Flow of login process in adf security

Tags: oracle-adf

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
Subject login = Authentication.login(new URLCallbackHandler(username, getPassword().getBytes()));
ServletAuthentication.runAs(login, request);
ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);

String loginUrl = "/adfAuthentication?success_url=/faces/homePage.jspx";

String activityURL = ctx.getGlobalViewActivityURL(loginUrl);
ext.redirect(activityURL);
```

Now suppose we are using AD server for user authentication, for the line where we are getting the Subject object how does weblogic know that its supposed to use the AD server provider setup in the weblogic. Can somebody explain the flow here if we are using AD server provider in weblogic?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue, actually the code works fine.. but the ad server settings were wrong. The users listed in the weblogic was the display name rather than the login-name.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The authentication sits on Weblogic Admin Server level, that means all Weblogic Managed Servers will share the same authentication logic. This further means all your deployed applications will share the same authentication.

To answer your question: Presuming you have 3 authentication providers in Weblogic:

1. DefaultAuthenticator
2. Active Directory Authenticator
3. SQL Authenticator

Suppose all have Control Flag Option set as SUFFICIENT:

When user tries to log on, first Weblogic will look among the users from "DefaultAuthenticator". If no user with right credentials is found, it moves to the "Active Directory Authenticator" and so on.

When a user with right credentials is found, authentication returns successful, without checking lower authenticators.

Comment: So you mean the code included should work if DefaultAuthenticator &
Active Directory Authenticator has flags set to SUFFICIENT. But this line is throwning FailedLoginException; Subject login = Authentication.login(new URLCallbackHandler(username, getPassword().getBytes()));

Comment: Have you tried deploying a Hello Word appication? Can you logon with it?